# Using Repeater in html page Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, html, asp

```
<!--SPM:<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrNavigation" DataSourceID="customSiteMap">-->
    <!--SPM:<HeaderTemplate>-->                                             
    <!--SPM:</HeaderTemplate>-->                
    <!--SPM:<ItemTemplate>-->
        <ul id="topmenulist">
            <li><a href='&lt;%# Eval("Url") %&gt;' class='&lt;%# Page.Request.Url.ToString().Contains(SPContext.Current.Site.Url + Eval("Url").ToString()) ? "topmenu-lnk-curr": "topmenu-lnk" %&gt;'>a</a>
            </li>         
        </ul>               
    <!--SPM:</ItemTemplate>-->
    <!--SPM:<FooterTemplate>-->
    <!--SPM:</FooterTemplate>-->
<!--SPM:</asp:Repeater>-->
```

This is my code. It is creating the right count of hyperlinks but the problem is that the hyperlink is not redirecting to the page but it takes all the things as text in the `<a>` tag.

Any ideas how to fix it? I have added the the `PageParserPath` thing in the web config and I have added to the root folder the sitemap which is required.

Comment: Check if u have added the correct sitemap

Answer (score 0):

Call a javascript function to fetch the class:

```
function getClass(url)
{
    string pageURL = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + url;

    if(Page.Request.Url.ToString().Contains(pageURL))
    {
        return "topmenu-lnk-curr";
    }
    else
    {
        return "topmenu-lnk";
    }
}
```

And try to assign the URL as per the below code:

```
<ul id="topmenulist">
    <li>
        <a href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "URL") %>' class='getClass(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "URL") %>);'>a</a>
    </li>         
</ul>
```